# We shouldn't have Segregated Core unless domain model is very complicated?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Evan's book, pg. 430:

> Therefore, although this example may not be complicated enough to
>   drive us to a Segregated Core ...

a) Is author implying that unless *domain model* is very complicated, we shouldn't have a *Segregated Core*? In other words, unless dealing with *complicated domain model*, a *Core Domain* should exist only in a *form of a documents* (  ie *Domain Vision Statement* and *Highlighted Core* ), but should not be manifested as *a separate physical entity*?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole set of domain driven pattern and methodologies should be used only with complex business domains.

"Complicated" is a pejorative that can be applied to the code model when it's not well designed or it doesn't provide the expressivity that a domain driven application requires. Moreover, a junior modeler could simply miss the point of the business itself and design a model more complex than the business (often in a quest for flexibility).

When you work with large and complex domains and with models that evolved during years, you often cumulate small modeling-debts, similar to the well known technical-debts. Then, refactoring towards a segregated core domain that should contain only the most valuable concepts and business rules (from the point of view of the customer), makes cheaper the evolution of the system (even if it's usually an expensive refactoring on its own).

However, when you need DDD, that's not just to write specifications' documents. You need DDD to understand and handle complex businesses, by expressing them in symbolic representations called "source code". To my money, DDD is a valuable business analysis tool, but its whole point is to enable coding of valuable applications that solve complex business problems.

Comment: "However, when you need DDD, that's not just to write specifications' documents. You need DDD to understand and handle complex businesses, by expressing them in symbolic rappresentations called "source code"."  I'm not sure if I understood your reply correctly, but it appears as if you're implying that not having a Segregated Core would mean that DDD is applied only on paper ( as a bunch of specification documents ), but not in source code? If so, I think you're mistaken, since author does mention several times that Segregated Core shouldn't always be applied when doing DDD

Comment: No. You said "In other words, unless dealing with complicated domain model, a Core Domain should exist **only in a form of a documents**". So I told you that, while useful to that purpose, DDD is not aimed to write documents and specifications, but running code. Nothing related to segregated core. Indeed I explained that in my own experience a segregated core often emerges after the **refactoring** of an existing and well designed domain model. Refactoring done to make the model even better, more manteinable and easier to evolve. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll try to rephrase what I said earlier: Core Domain should be "physically separated from other domain code" / "directly visible in code" only when the model is complicated enough. But when model is not complicated enough, then it's enough to identify the Core Domain only via  Domain Vision Statement and Highlighted Core?

Comment: If the domain is not **complex** enough **you should avoid DDD**. While actively sponsored by first-class software companies and developers, **Buzzword-Driven-Development** is the most expensive and less effective technique that exists. You should always choose the proper tool for the job: if the domain is simple, DDD is not the right one. DDD is useful when the problem is so complex that [even the architecture or the technology you choose becomes a detail](http://epic.tesio.it/doc/manual/nothing_but_business.html). If you need DDD, you have a Core Domain to model **and** code.

Comment: I know that you have far greater knowledge about DDD and programming in general, but Evans said in his book that even if the domain is not complex enough to justify the use of Segregated Core, we could still use DDD ( assuming domain is complex enough to justify the use of DDD ). But you appear to be saying just the opposite - if the domain is not complex enough to have a Segregated Core, then we shouldn't even be using DDD?" Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Well, may be I can't explain this well enough. A Core Domain (p.400 of the blue book) is the domain of the problem that justifies the development 's investment. You can invest in a Segregated Core during the application evolution, **refactoring** the model to strengthen the cohesion of the CORE, improving its general quality and reducing the "modeling debts" cumulated over years. You need DDD if your domain is complex. You need a Segregated Core if your complex domain **evolves** since, otherwise, it could become expensive to maintain.

Comment: This is high level, conceptual 'guidance' that doesn't give a junior developer actionable information. It is true, in the sense that if you're writing `InsertionSort` and you're trying to use DDD, you're probably doing it wrong. But that's a truism. Arm wavy answers like this without specific examples of how these types of concepts are applied in practice only confuse would-be practitioners.

Answer (score 2):

To me, a Segregated Core refers to organising domain components into completely separate packages, but together represent the same core domain. A large core may benefit from this type of organisation to clarify the composition of the domain, or to separate supporting capabilities from core domain concepts.

Answer (score 1):

"a Core Domain should exist only in a form of a documents ( ie Domain Vision Statement and Highlighted Core ),"

No. Your core domain should never exist as only a set of documents. That defeats the point of Domain Driven Design. The ENTIRE POINT of DDD is that your business analysis artifacts have First Class representations within your system. For example, if your requirements regularly discuss the concept of a ShippingCargo's Route, and you don't have *classes* (code level artifacts) for **ShippingCargo** and **Route**, you're doing it wrong. The point of a **Ubiquitous Language** is that there's a tight mapping between what we say the software does and what it actually does.

The technique is meant to manage Cognitive Load, and reduce impedence mismatch of terminology and reasoning about the system by different stakeholders.

Holding your model only in documents is a case of violating [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Similar to [code comments and the various arguments against them](http://elegantcode.com/2010/04/18/eliminating-comments-the-road-to-clarity/), documents become stale and lose value. I cannot stress this enough, the entire point of DDD is that your code should be able to manifest the **Core Domain** with minimal support from non-code documentation.

A Segregated Core specifically is useful when the number of Domain objects (Entities, Value Objects, etc) becomes so large that it makes sense, for cohesion and architectural simplicity, to split things apart.

Applied Examples of this concept

- [Spock Framework](http://code.google.com/p/spock/source/browse/#svn/trunk)
- [Maven](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=maven.git;a=commit;h=01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da)
- [Geotools](https://github.com/geotools/geotools)

Watch the evolution of their code bases (you may need to browse for the past couple of years to see how things change). You'll notice that as these systems got bigger, and interfaced with more external systems, the idea of a "core" module became important. That's the Segregated Core.

Answer (score 1):

on pg. 429 Evans states:

> The time to chop out a segregated core is when you have a large bounded context that is critical to the system, but where the essential part of the model is being obscured by a great deal of supporting capability.

Segregated Core is just a **refactoring technique** that you can use that is aimed to refine the the core model so it evolves into a conceptually more cohesive model. Moving elements **that only partially serve the CORE DOMAIN** into separate supporting contexts is what segregated core tells you to do.